# How can I get STAT column in ps command?

Tags: cygwin

I installed Cygwin for 64 bit versions of Windows.and I run "Cygwin64 Terminal" in order to confirm whole process' state. As far as I know, ps command must show STAT column but It is impossible to find STAT column Whenever I execute "ps -l" or "ps aux" ,"ps -ef", "ps axj"..
I really want to view STAT column in ps command because a source code which I practice recently request me to check zombie process by means of ps command.

[screenshot of ps command without STAT column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CQ2p.png)

Comment: The `ps` on Cygwin64 is not the same as on Linux. The documentation for `ps` for Cygwin says, *Due to the limitations of simulating a POSIX environment under Windows, there is little information to give.*

Comment: Then..Is there no way to view STAT column of ps command under windows circumstance of Cygwin64?

Comment: You'll need to check the manual for `ps` under cygwin and see if there's an option that will work. I just tried `ps aux` under Git Bash, but it would not show STAT. However, `ps aux` under GNU Bash in Windows 10, and it showed STAT. So it depends upon the shell implementation. Looks like you already tried `-f` which is what I would have suggested for Cygwin. You may be out of luck on Cygwin.

Comment: I finally give up to use Cygwin anymore...Now I installed lubuntu 16.04 in virtualbox of virtual machine..Thank you again for your reply which help me a lot.

Comment: You mighy also consider the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). It's Ubuntu that runs right on Windows. Performance is very good.

Answer (score 0):

Use `procps`

```
$ /usr/bin/procps.exe ax
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 1580 pty1     Ss     0:00 -bash
 1624 pty0     R      0:00 /usr/bin/procps ax
 1522 ?        Ss     0:05 /usr/bin/mintty -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -
 1599 pty1     T      0:00 less .bashrc
 1523 pty0     Ss     0:00 -bash
 1579 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/bin/mintty -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -
```

you can find it in `procps-ng` package

```
$ cygcheck -f /usr/bin/procps
procps-ng-3.3.16-1
```